# trying to fetch content from local text file XMLHttprequest in Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ubuntu

I need to fetch data from ubuntu local text file. I tried with XMLHttpRequest, where readyState is always 1 and Status is always 0. ResponseText is null and statusText is also null.

If this doesn't work for local file, what is an alternative for this?? My requirement is to fetch content from the local file and parse it and use it. I even tried AJAX which has same origin policy(this doesn't help me).

Please help!!

Comment: use an <input type=file > and FileReader or URL.createObjectURL() to grab the file data

Comment: I'm not using HTML in my code. It's purely JQuery. Could you please let me know how can i do the same with Jquery/Javascript

Comment: you can create an input with jQuery, then have the user click on it to select a file. or you can drag and drop a file into the browser and use html5 drag-and-drop events to catch the file, again using FileReader or URL.createObjectURL()